# Sum $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!k^k}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I came across this crazy sum, and I have no idea how to tackle it

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!k^k}.$$

I tried to approximate it using wolfram alpha widget,

and got something like $1.13134$.

However, I'd like to get an exact solution.

EDIT: i was thinking that maybe we could play around with the ceiling function a little bit. 
Consider that:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!k^k}.$$

is actually the area under the curve

$$f(k)=\frac{1}{\left\lceil{k^k}\right\rceil}\frac{1}{\left\lceil{k!}\right\rceil}$$

from $0$ to $\infty$. More formally, this can be expressed as:
$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\left\lceil{k^k}\right\rceil}\frac{1}{\left\lceil{k!}\right\rceil} dk=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!k^k}.$$

If we multiply $I$ by:
$$L=\int_0^\infty{\left\lceil{k^k}\right\rceil}{\left\lceil{k!}\right\rceil} e^{-k}dk.$$

We get that:

$$I L=\int_0^\infty e^{-k} dk=1.$$

Hence:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!k^k}\int_0^\infty{\left\lceil{k^k}\right\rceil}{\left\lceil{k!}\right\rceil} e^{-k}dk=1,$$

so if we could somehow evaluate $L$, then it might be possible to calculate the sum.

Unfortunately, I'm not sure if this reasoning works.

Comment: Exact solution, seems impossible with **Earth** math.

Comment: $\displaystyle{1 \over k!\, k^{k}} = \left[z^{k}\right]\mathrm{e}^{z/k}$.

Comment: I'd like to point out in general $\left(\int_0^\infty f(x) dx\right)\left(\int_0^\infty g(x) dx\right) \ne \int_0^\infty f(x) g(x) dx$ so your $IL=1$ identity is false. (In fact, the integral $L$ diverges).

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid I have to concur with @MariuszIwaniuk. I'll summarise what I found.

In a variant on the famous [sophomore's dream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream#Proof) calculation, note first that, since in terms of [modified Bessel functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1) $\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{y^n}{n!(n+1)!}=\frac{I_1(2\sqrt{y})}{\sqrt{y}}$, the substitution $u=-\ln x$ obtains $$\int_0^1\frac{I_1(2\sqrt{-x\ln x})}{\sqrt{-x\ln x}}dx=\sum_{n\ge 0}\frac{(-1)^n}{n!(n+1)!}\int_0^1(x\ln x)^ndx=\sum_n\frac{\int_0^1u^ne^{-(n+1)u}du}{n!(n+1)!}=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac{1}{k!k^k}.$$Now we just need to evaluate that integral... [which seems equally impossible](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+BesselI%5B1,+2*sqrt(-x*ln+x)%5D%2Fsqrt(-x*ln+x)+from+0+to+1). I also had no luck identifying the value with the [inverse symbolic calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/cgi-bin/isc/lookup?number=1.13133829660062637&lookup_type=simple).